# Minimal way of connecting a producer and two consumers both point to point and broadcast on HornetQ

Tags: java, hornetq

Maybe the title is not very descriptive.

The case is the following, there's a system with one server, one producer and 1..n consumers.

Messages will be sent either directly to one consumer or to a broadcast so every consumer receives the message.

I'm actually thinking of creating one queue for each consumer for direct communication and then another queue for the broadcast messages. This way consumers should poll two queues for messages: it's own and the broadcast one.

The actual question is: **is there a way of doing this without the broadcast queue (so the consumers will only poll one queue)?**

---

I actually solved this using diverts on runtime.

Comment: Using diverts for the broadcast address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking. But you don't send to a queue, you send to an Address:

In hornetq-core terms:

The producer will send to an Address, and you can create one or many queues on that address

In JMS Terms, you could create either a JMS Queue or a JMS Topic, and you could create message subscription.

also... there's a feature on hornetq about [Topics Hierarchy](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.Alpha/docs/user-manual/html/examples.html#topic-hierarchy-example) where you can create queues with Wildcards. Maybe that will help you achieve what you needed.

I can improve this answer if you provide me a little bit more context.

You can also look on Diverts. Look at the HornetQ Documentation for more details.

Comment: Just in case, I'll try to detail a bit more. Everything I'm doing is hornet-core.

What I wanted to do was to was to have consumers poll only one queue. This way there would be one address for each consumer's queue (Eg. `"Consumer1"`) for messages addressed only to them (the producer would send the message to address `"Consumer1"`. But also, there would be another address `"Broadcast"` mapped to each consumer's specific address, so the producer would send one message to address `"Broadcast"` and a copy of that message would appear on every consumers queue.

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Comment: Diverts?  Take a look on the documentation!

Comment: Please correct my if I'm wrong, but from the documentation I've extracted that diverts only copy one message from one address to another. This meaning that if I send a message to `Broadcast` I can divert that to `Consumer1`. So, how do I divert it also to `ConsumerN`? Do I create another divert from `Broadcast` to `ConsumerN`? Or did I undestood the documentation wrong and several addresses can be set on one divert?

Comment: you can have multiple diverts on an address. you can make it non-exclusive and that should work.

Also, take a look at wildcards queues on the docs, and hierarchical topics. I'm not sure which one will fit best your needs.

Comment: If diverts can route a message sent to address `broadcast` to both `consumer1` and `consumer2` then that's all I need (at least for the moment). I'll accept the answer as this comment solves my question.